# RS485-Protection(signal (A-B) from input voltage (12v and 24v )using TVS diode

Tags: diodes, protection, zener, rs485, tvs

To protect RS485 signals differential (A/B) from power input (12 and 24 V), we can use TVS diodes.

TVS diode parameters:
There are many types of TVS diode in the market, designed for a specific application. When you are selecting a TVS diode you can look for the following terminologies in the datasheet to suit your design.

1. Reverse Stand-Off Voltage (VR): Reverse stand-off voltage is the maximum voltage that can be applied to the protector without actually activating the device. The device VR should be equal to, or higher than the peak operating voltage of the circuit being protected. This is to ensure that the protection device does not clip the normal circuit operating or signal voltage.
2. Breakdown Voltage (VBR): Breakdown voltage is the voltage at which the diode will begin to protect and conduct current. Generally, the VBR is specified at 1 mA.
3. Clamping Voltage (VC): Clamping voltage is the highest voltage that the protected circuit will be exposed to during the test waveform event. On most datasheets, the clamping voltage is given for a 1 or 2 A waveform that has an 8 µs rise time.
4. Peak Pulse Current (IPP): The peak pulse current is the maximum current the protection device can withstand.

I followed these rules and I select the reference "SMBJ12CA" but I don't agree with V clamp.
Is this reference right for protecting RS485 from input power (12/24 V)?
Please help me.

Comment: Please ask an unambiguous question

Comment: What do you disagree with about Vclamp and why?

Comment: IN THE DATASHEET SMBJ12CA V clamp is 19.9V which means the maximum voltage you can resist with Ipp is equal to 30.2A but I have 24v in my power input 24v >>19.9v this is my explication that I don't agree from clamp thank you for response

Comment: If you're trying to use a TVS to protect a RS485 transceiver, then the TVS Vclamp needs to be lower than the txcvr max voltage. If the txcvr max voltage is 12v then you can't use a SMBJ12 with a Vclamp of 19.9V. Your power supply voltage is not really relevant to that choice unless you're also trying to protect the supply line - in which case you'd use lower voltage TVS's on the RS485 lines and a higher voltage TVS on the supply line.